# Fluent UI Reading the height of DetailsList's ViewPort

Tags: javascript, typescript, fluent-ui, office-fabric, fluentui-react

I'm using `DetalisList` within `ScrollablePane` component to keep the header in view, and let the rows scrollable. However, this requires me to manually set the height of the scrollable container.

```
div.scrollable-container
    ScrollablePane
        DetailsList
```

When I investigate the DOM elements for DetalisList, I can see that it's wrapped inside a ViewPort element. The height of this element is the actual height of the sum of the height of all components that make up the list (column headers, rows. etc.). Thus, I want to be able to read this value and set the container height based on whether it exceeds a certain value or not.

Is there a nice to way to access the height of the ViewPort? I can always query the DOM, and find the element, but I'd like to avoid relying on the internal structure of the component.

So, far I could not find any information on this. I noticed `DetailsList` takes a prop called `viewport`, but I don't think this is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try by giving height in "vh" (viewport height) unit. For example,

```
const gridContainerStyle: IStackStyles = {
   root: { height: "70vh", position: "relative" },
 };
```